# "You've earned a badge" does not set appropriate activity filter in user profile

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

When you click on the *profile* link in the message bar notifying about a new badge, you are taken to the *activity* section of your profile.

[image]

The last selected filter (e.g. *comments*) is still applied, so you don't necessarily see any badges. After clicking the link in the message above, I was taken here:

[image]

This is obviously not useful and rather confusing.

Similar behavior might occur with the *new comment* or *new answer* notifications and filters applied to the *responses* section.

---

Please change the link in the notification message to jump to the correctly filtered list of the *activity* (or other) section. Bonus points if the user-selected filter is not changed, i.e. the next view of that page displays the user-selected filtered list instead of the filtered list used to display the object the user was notified about.

Comment: If you try to reproduce this behavior, make sure to reload the page. The activity/responses lists are cached.